# How to copy multiple file from local to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to upload multiple files from my local to an AWS S3 bucket,
I am able to use `aws s3 cp` to copy files one by one,
But I need to upload multiple but not all ie. selective files to the same S3 folder,
Is it possible to do this in a single AWS CLI call, if so how?

Eg -

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test.txt
```

**Reference -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Answer (score 47):

If you scroll down the documentation link you provided to the section entitled "Recursively copying local files to S3", you will see the following:

> When passed with the parameter --recursive, the following cp command recursively copies all files under a specified directory to a specified bucket and prefix while excluding some files by using an --exclude parameter. In this example, the directory myDir has the files test1.txt and test2.jpg

So, assuming you wanted to copy all `.txt` files in some subfolder to the same bucket in S3, you could try something like:

```
aws s3 cp yourSubFolder s3://mybucket/ --recursive
```

If there are any other files in this subfolder, you need to add the `--exclude` and `--include` parameters (otherwise all files will be uploaded):

```
aws s3 cp yourSubFolder s3://mybucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"
```

Comment: how can achieve upload -> a.txt, b.txt but skip -> c.txt and d.txt

Comment: I didn't see any way to do exactly this from the documentation, at least no examples were given.

Comment: yea cause, I wish to selective upload, would be dangerous for me to just upload all files of the extension that I want.

Comment: Is there any chance you can get all desired upload files into a single subfolder?

Comment: yea was thinking the same then use the `aws s3 sync` to sync them to the s3 folder?

Comment: I think you can use include and exclude flags with RegEx.

aws s3 cp yourSubFolder s3://mybucket/ --recursive --include "a*.txt" --include "b*.txt" --exclude="c*.txt" --exclude="d*.txt"

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing this from bash, then you can use this pattern as well:

```
for f in *.png; do aws s3 cp $f s3://my/dest; done
```

You would of course customize `*.png` to be your glob pattern, and the `s3` destination.

If you have a weird set of files you can do something like put their names in a text file, call it `filenames.txt` and then:

```
for f in `cat filenames.txt`; do ... (same as above) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aws s3 cp <your directory path> s3://<your bucket name>/ --recursive --exclude "*.jpg"  --include "*.log”
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/usage) (rather than the aws CLI), you can specify as many source files as you want.

For example, to upload all *.iso files in the current directory:

```
$ s3cmd put --no-preserve --multipart-chunk-size-mb=50 *.iso "s3://my-bucket/backups/"
```

Also, s3cmd handles uploads of large files well, since it automatically retries individual parts that temporarily fail to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way when you can't copy file from local to cluster:-

`Step 1.` Add a file using `nano` or copy from your local to the cluster

ex.

```
>> nano test_folder/abc.txt
```

CTRL + X -> Enter Yes and it will exit

`Step 2.` Type `pwd` in command prompt and get the file location of the source

```
>>pwd 
>>home/mynamehpb
```

Then location will be `home/mynamehpb/test_folder/abc.txt`

`Step 3` Use `aws cp` command and copy the file to the destination

```
aws s3 cp /home/mynamehpb/test_folder/abc.txt s3://company-bucket/folder/abc.txt
```

`Step 4` If encryption key required, use `sse` command.

```
aws s3 cp /home/mynamehpb/test_folder/abc.txt s3://company-bucket/folder/abc.txt -sse ABC123
```

This should do the job when you are unable to copy file from local to cluster.